# How to slowly migrate a huge amount of data from one PostgreSQL server to another?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, data-migration

I have a postgres database which holds a big portion of data (~400 GB). I need to transfer it to another postgres instance set up on a different server which I need to migrate that data to. What are my options?

Both DBs live in k8s pods within AWS, pods are orchestrated using the same k8s instance but are otherwise independent. Also, the destination DB is under a serious write load, so I would prefer migrating the data slowly, maybe over the course of several days, to keep the extra write load minimal.

I understand that there are standard ways using `pg_dump` and `dblink`, but if I understand correctly `pg_dump` needs to first create an export file in full, which is not really feasible considering the DB size, while `dblink` would try to select the whole data which falls under the `SELECT * FROM ...` query, so it would also fail.

One more thing about the data I need to migrate is that it has a `timestamp` field and is distributed more or less evenly across a long time range. But I don't know if there's a way to run something purely on the PG server side which would in a loop fetch data for a small period of time, store it locally, and then move to the next period of time.

If all else fails I'll just have to write a standalone ad-hoc service which I'll deploy alongside those DB services to do exactly that. But I'd prefer a solution based on already existing tools.

Answer (score 1):

I had great success in the past by **creating a pipeline between two PostgreSQL databases**. This is possible because `pg_dump` actually creates normal SQL that is the 'fed into' the destination database:

```
$ pg_dump <from first database> | pgsql <to second database>
```

Instead of creating an export file, it just sends the export to the other database.

I only did it one table at-a-time, and I only did it for the table data, but you can tell `pg_dump` whether to include schema and table definitions, or just the data.

Actually, I'd recommend doing it first just to create the schema and tables, and then do a separate run to just copy the data. That way, if something goes wrong, you can just copy specific tables. It also gives you a chance to verify the schema (which should be quick) before copying the data (which should be slow).

I ran the command on a separate computer, so effectively it was going `db -> computer -> db`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But what about the rate limiting? Is there a way to make `pg_dump` stay under a certain data dump speed, or will it go greedy and try to consume as much bandwidth as possible?

Comment: You could create a batch file to migrate one table at a time. That way, the next step will only begin once the data has been loaded in the target database with psql. This will keep things slow since inserting data is much slower than retrieving data.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an python script to get it done.
Actually there is already a script [here](https://github.com/microsoft/OrcasNinjaTeam/tree/master/azure-postgresql/data_migration) which could be found in github. It is a script with the goal to move lots of data between postgresql databases quickly, which is not same with your requirement, but I think you can easily custom it to introduce some logic to limit the rate.
Hope this is helpful.